# How to get both score and accuracy after training

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size,
     nb_epoch = 4, validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
     show_accuracy = True)    
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, 
     batch_size = batch_size, show_accuracy = True, verbose=0)
```

gives scalar output and hence the following code doesn't work.

```
print("Test score", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])
```

The output that I get is:
    Train on 20000 samples, validate on 5000 samples

```
Epoch 1/4

20000/20000 [==============================] - 352s - loss: 0.4515 - val_loss: 0.4232

Epoch 2/4

20000/20000 [==============================] - 381s - loss: 0.2592 - val_loss: 0.3723

 Epoch 3/4

 20000/20000 [==============================] - 374s - loss: 0.1513 - val_loss: 0.4329

 Epoch 4/4

 20000/20000 [==============================] - 380s - loss: 0.0838 - val_loss: 0.5044
```

Keras version 1.0

How can I get the accuracy as well? Please help

Comment: What do you mean by test score? Is it test loss?

Comment: Could you print history.history.keys()?

Comment: The keys are loss and val_loss.

Comment: Try to add metrics = ["accuracy"] to fit arguments.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Sequential` model you can try (**CODE UPDATED**):

```
nb_epochs = 4
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size,
 nb_epoch = nb_epochs, validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
 show_accuracy = True)

print("Test score", history.history["val_loss"][nb_epochs - 1])
print("Test acc", history.history["val_acc"][nb_epochs - 1])
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin but my model does not generate any val_acc field as is seen from the output of model.fit. I am guessing the show_accuracy = True argument doesnt work in my case

Comment: Could you print what kind of fields does your history dictionary have (by e.g. printing it)? Do you use Sequential model? What version of Keras do you have?

Comment: I use the Sequential model

Comment: this gives the error Received unknown keyword arguments: {'metrics': ['accuracy']}. I checked in the source code (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/legacy/models.py) and there it seems the callbacks argument is my safest bet. Will try that part tomorrow. Thanks for the help Marcin. Ciao!

Comment: Yes - I found my mistake - you should add metrics = ["accuracy"] to compile arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Marcin and you are correct.

The code needs to be like this

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer = 'adam',
          metrics=["accuracy"])
```

show_accuracy serves no purpose in model.fit and needs to be removed from there.